# eroors in sqlite database occourd in retriving the data from the table in android

Tags: android, sqlite

my DataHandler activity code is

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataHandlerDairy {

public static final String DATE = "date";
public static final String DAIRY = "dairy";
private static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "mydairy";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_dairy";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table table_diary       (date text primary key," + "dairy text not null);";

DataBaseHelper1 dbhelper1;
Context ct;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DataHandlerDairy(Context ct)
{
    this.ct=ct;
    dbhelper1 = new DataBaseHelper1(ct);

}

private static class DataBaseHelper1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

public DataBaseHelper1(Context ct)
{
    super(ct,DATA_BASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_dairy ");
    onCreate(db);
}

} 

public DataHandlerDairy open()
{
db = dbhelper1.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}

public void close()
{
    dbhelper1.close();
}

public long insertData(String date,String dairy)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(DATE, date);
    content.put(DAIRY, dairy);
    return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}

public Cursor returnData(String date1) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] { DATE, DAIRY}, DATE + "=" + date1, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

And when i try to use the save operation ie `insertData()` method in the DataHandler Activity. And storing the date I have got the date from another activity using Intents.

The code for Saving data into database is

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Write_Dairy extends Activity {

EditText et1;
ImageButton correct,wrong;
DataHandlerDairy handler2;
String getdate;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_write__dairy);




    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.writediary);
    correct=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.correct1);
    wrong=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.wrong1);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    getdate = bundle.getString("message");


    correct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String getdairy = et1.getText().toString();
            handler2 = new DataHandlerDairy(getBaseContext());
            handler2.open();
            long id = handler2.insertData(getdate,getdairy);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "your dairy is saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handler2.close();

            Intent ijk = new Intent(Write_Dairy.this,PickYourDate.class);
            startActivity(ijk);

        }
    });

    wrong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please write your dairy again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            et1.setText("");

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_write__dairy, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and for retriving the data i have used the date as primary key which i used it as string in both sql and java. the code for retriveing the data is

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Read_Dairy extends Activity {


String date1;
TextView tv1;
ImageButton imgb1;
Button bt1;
DataHandlerDairy handler3;
String getdata=" ";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read__dairy);



    tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.readme);
    imgb1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tick);
    bt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ready);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    date1 = bundle.getString("kanna");



    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler3 = new DataHandlerDairy(getBaseContext());
            handler3.open();
            Cursor c = handler3.returnData(date1);
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                getdata=c.getString(1);

                }while(c.moveToNext());             
                }
            handler3.close();

            if(getdata==null)
            {
                tv1.setText("no data exists for this date");
            }
            else
            {
            tv1.setText(c.getString(1));
            }

        }

    });


    imgb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent ks = new Intent(Read_Dairy.this,PickYourDate.class);
            startActivity(ks);

        }
    });

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Strato-linked.ttf");
    tv1.setTypeface(font);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_read__dairy, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The stack trace while i tried to store data is

> ```
> E/SQLiteLog(16724): (1) no such table: table_dairy
>  D/AndroidRuntime(16724): Shutting down VM
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724): Process: simple.smile.my_dairy, PID: 16724
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_dairy (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_dairy(date,dairy) VALUES (?,?)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1367)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at simple.smile.my_dairy.DataHandlerDairy.insertData(DataHandlerDairy.java:79)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at simple.smile.my_dairy.Write_Dairy$1.onClick(Write_Dairy.java:48)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>  E/AndroidRuntime(16724):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>  AndroidRuntime(16724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
> E/AndroidRuntime(16724):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
> ```

Will anyone please tell what is the mistake i have done and how can the error be solved.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your table name mismatches:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_dairy"; // DAIRY?????
```

and

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table table_diary (date text primary key," + "dairy text not null);";
```

This

```
return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
```

Tries to insert into **table_dairy**, while you created **table_diary**.
So, it correctly tells you that **table_dairy** does not exist.

Comment: Correct answer. I would add to remember to uninstall and reinstall the application if you change your table because you need to clear the database.

Comment: ... or simply increase the value of the constant `DATABASE_VERSION`, in order to make the `onUpgrade()` event fire.

Comment: Yes, this is another one way

Comment: ... and? did you try?

Comment: yes i have tried to change the values in upgrade(). I am getting an error if I try to change the version of dattabase.

Comment: 2 - Change this `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to this `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;`